# Unable to install optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin

Tags: npm, webpack

My error when trying to install  `npm install --save-dev optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin`

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: webpack@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.33.2
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^5.33.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   dev optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-16T17_32_37_320Z-debug.log
```

I have already updated webpack and npm. I checked the [installation page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin) and it mentions that I should have the most recent webpack. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From going to the github repo, they actually mention to use [css-minimizer-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin) for webpack 5.0

Comment: In addition to to this, I actually was stuck on the npm install so after deleting package.lock.json and reinstalling it was fine.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @pythonNovice, my config is as follows:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin")
...
//const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin")
```

In the optimization section:

```
minimize: true,
minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin(), // optional
    new CssMinimizerPlugin()
    //new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save-dev optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).